# Wait for a single RabbitMQ message with a timeout

Tags: .net, python, rabbitmq, amqp, py-amqplib

I'd like to send a message to a RabbitMQ server and then wait for a reply message (on a "reply-to" queue). Of course, I don't want to wait forever in case the application processing these messages is down - there needs to be a timeout. It sounds like a very basic task, yet I can't find a way to do this. I've now run into this problem with both [py-amqplib](http://code.google.com/p/py-amqplib/) and the [RabbitMQ .NET client](http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html).

The best solution I've got so far is to poll using `basic_get` with `sleep` in-between, but this is pretty ugly:

```
def _wait_for_message_with_timeout(channel, queue_name, timeout):
    slept = 0
    sleep_interval = 0.1

    while slept < timeout:
        reply = channel.basic_get(queue_name)
        if reply is not None:
            return reply

        time.sleep(sleep_interval)
        slept += sleep_interval

    raise Exception('Timeout (%g seconds) expired while waiting for an MQ response.' % timeout)
```

Surely there is some better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just added timeout support for `amqplib` in `carrot`.

This is a subclass of `amqplib.client0_8.Connection`:

http://github.com/ask/carrot/blob/master/carrot/backends/pyamqplib.py#L19-97

`wait_multi` is a version of `channel.wait` able to receive on an arbitrary number
of channels.

I guess this could be merged upstream at some point.

Comment: Now this is what I call a "great answer": "it's fixed"! Accepting - in the hope that it *is* merged into amqplib.

Comment: @EMP haha :) funny :)

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I ended up doing in the .NET client:

```
protected byte[] WaitForMessageWithTimeout(string queueName, int timeoutMs)
{
    var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(Channel);
    var tag = Channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, null, consumer);
    try
    {
        object result;
        if (!consumer.Queue.Dequeue(timeoutMs, out result))
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Timeout ({0} seconds) expired while waiting for an MQ response.", timeoutMs / 1000.0));

        return ((BasicDeliverEventArgs)result).Body;
    }
    finally
    {
        Channel.BasicCancel(tag);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot do the same with py-amqplib, because its `basic_consume` method does not call the callback unless you call `channel.wait()` and `channel.wait()` doesn't support timeouts! This silly limitation (which I keep running into) means that if you never receive another message your thread is frozen forever.

Answer (score 2):

There's an example [here](http://old.nabble.com/python-hello-world-td17051682.html) using [qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/download.html) with a `msg = q.get(timeout=1)` that should do what you want.  Sorry, I don't know what other AMQP client libraries implement timeouts (and in particular I don't know the two specific ones you mentioned).

Comment: Looking at the source of qpid it seems to use the exact same approach as the .NET client: `basic_consume` with a queue and waiting on the queue with a timeout. Looks like that's what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to break the whole idea of asynchronous processing, but if you must I think the right way to do it is to use an [RpcClient](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html).

Comment: While RpcClient itself is not useful to me, looking at its implementation reveals the approach to use: create a `QueueingBasicConsumer` and wait on its queue, which supports a timeout. This isn't as complex in .NET as I feared.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbit now allows for you to add timeout events. Simply wrap your code in a try catch and then throw exceptions in the TimeOut and Disconnect handlers:

```
try{
    using (IModel channel = rabbitConnection.connection.CreateModel())
    {
        client = new SimpleRpcClient(channel, "", "", queue);
        client.TimeoutMilliseconds = 5000; // 5 sec. defaults to infinity
        client.TimedOut += RpcTimedOutHandler;
        client.Disconnected += RpcDisconnectedHandler;
        byte[] replyMessageBytes = client.Call(message);
        return replyMessageBytes;
    }
}
catch (Exception){
    //Handle timeout and disconnect here
}
private void RpcDisconnectedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     throw new Exception("RPC disconnect exception occured.");
}

private void RpcTimedOutHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     throw new Exception("RPC timeout exception occured.");
}
```