# py-amqp/flopsy: Waiting for a single AMQP message in Python

Tags: python, amqp, py-amqplib, flopsy

I have a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799731/wait-for-a-single-rabbitmq-message-with-a-timeout): It's very easy in py-amqp/flopsy to say "I'm going to wait forever, and I want this callback to be called whenever a message comes in," but I can't find any way of saying "OK, I got the message I want now stop waiting." (Maybe a GOTO? Just kidding...) Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, maybe this should have been obvious to me: If you register a callback in flopsy (which is a thin wrapper around amqplib) with

```
consumer.register('kind', callback_func)
consumer.wait()
# more code goes here...
```

then you can `raise` an Exception in `callback_func` to get to the rest of the code.

**Bonus question**: How do I set a maximum timeout for the `wait()` in case a response is never received? Let's say that this is in the context of a `unittest` test case.