# RabbitMQ Wait for a message with a timeout

Tags: rabbitmq

I'd like to send a message to a RabbitMQ server and then wait for a reply message (on a "reply-to" queue). Of course, I don't want to wait forever in case the application processing these messages is down - there needs to be a timeout. It sounds like a very basic task, yet I can't find a way to do this. I've now run into this problem with Java API.

Answer (score 4):

The RabbitMQ Java client library now [supports a timeout argument to its `QueueConsumer.nextDelivery()` method](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.1/com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer.html#nextDelivery(long)).

For instance, the RPC tutorial uses the following code:

```java
channel.basicPublish("", requestQueueName, props, message.getBytes());

while (true) {
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
    if (delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
        response = new String(delivery.getBody());
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use `consumer.nextDelivery(1000)` to wait for maximum one second. If the timeout is reached, the method returns `null`.

```java
channel.basicPublish("", requestQueueName, props, message.getBytes());

while (true) {
    // Use a timeout of 1000 milliseconds
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(1000);

    // Test if delivery is null, meaning the timeout was reached.
    if (delivery != null &&
        delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
        response = new String(delivery.getBody());
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer` has a `nextDelivery(long timeout)` method, which will do what you want. However, this has been deprecated. 
Writing your own timeout isn't so hard, although it may be better to have an ongoing thread and a list of in-time identifiers, rather than adding and removing consumers and associated timeout threads all the time.

Edit to add: Noticed the date on this after replying!

Answer (score 0):

There is similar question. Although it's answers doesn't use java, maybe you can get some hints.

[Wait for a single RabbitMQ message with a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799731/wait-for-a-single-rabbitmq-message-with-a-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I approached this problem using C# by creating an object to keep track of the response to a particular message. It sets up a unique reply queue for a message, and subscribes to it. If the response is not received in a specified timeframe, a countdown timer cancels the subscription, which deletes the queue. Separately, I have methods that can be synchronous from my main thread (uses a semaphore) or asynchronous (uses a callback) to utilize this functionality.

Basically, the implementation looks like this:

```
//Synchronous case:
//Throws TimeoutException if timeout happens
var msg = messageClient.SendAndWait(theMessage);

//Asynchronous case
//myCallback receives an exception message if there is a timeout
messageClient.SendAndCallback(theMessage, myCallback);
```